# PHP Millimeter (mm) to Inch (in) and Kilogram (kg) to Pound (lb) Convert

Tags: php

Hi I'm trying to convert Millimeter (mm) to Inch (in) and Kilogram (kg) to Pound (lb) Convert in PHP. Is there any function that does this ? How would I do this ? Thank you.

Comment: There is actually a generic way to convert any unit to any other unit.  You just need the conversion factor (you can find various ones online, google is a really good place to start).  The function you're looking for is `*`.

Comment: Why do you need a function for this? It's a simple multiplication. Also, what has the imagemagick tag got to do with this question?

Comment: It is simple multiplication but for a site needing localization there is a valid reason for having a good reusable approach.  Nothing native to PHP.  Write your own or look at something like [Zend_Measure](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.measure.edit.html).

Comment: The best thing I've found so far is ceil($mm/25.4) but its not presise. For example if I do 1984 mm it will show 79 istead of 78.11 or at least 78.1 It rounds numbers.

Comment: Yes I know about google. I need to code my own. Thanks for Zend class will check it out.

Comment: @Tux: It rounds numbers, because you tell PHP to round numbers (up) with `ceil`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can write your own functions like this very easily.

```
function mmToIn ($val) {
  return $val * 0.0393701
}

function kgToLb ($val) {
  return $val * 2.20462
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need write you own code for these operations (cos I have never heard about any built in function that doing what you want).

First: https://www.google.com/search?q=millimeter+to+inches

Second:

```
function mil_to_inc($mil) {
   $inc = 0.0393700787;
   return $mil * $inc;
}

// example
$_5_mil_to_inc = mil_to_inc(5); // will give you 0.196850394 etc..
```